# Lagom properties in build.sbt

Tags: scala, properties, configuration, sbt, lagom

Is there somewhere a list of all Lagom properties that can be used in build.sbt?

Example:

```
lagomServiceLocatorPort in ThisBuild := 12321
lagomServiceGatewayPort in ThisBuild := 13531
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source code in [`LagomPlugin.scala`](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/1.3.x/dev/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/lagom/sbt/LagomPlugin.scala#L259) (1.3.x branch):

```
val lagomRun = taskKey[(String, DevServer)]("Run a Lagom service")
val runAll = taskKey[Unit]("Run all Lagom services")

val lagomServicesPortRange = settingKey[PortRange]("Port range used to assign a port to each Lagom service in the build")

val lagomFileWatchService = settingKey[FileWatchService]("The file watch service to use")
val lagomDevSettings = settingKey[Seq[(String, String)]]("Settings that should be passed to a Lagom app in dev mode")
val lagomServicePort = taskKey[Int]("The port that the Lagom service should run on")

// service locator tasks and settings
val lagomUnmanagedServices = settingKey[Map[String, String]]("External services name and address known by the service location")
val lagomServiceLocatorUrl = settingKey[String]("URL of the service locator")
val lagomServiceLocatorPort = settingKey[Int]("Port used by the service locator")
val lagomServiceGatewayPort = settingKey[Int]("Port used by the service gateway")
val lagomServiceGatewayImpl = settingKey[String]("Implementation of the service gateway: \"netty\" (default) or \"akka-http\" (experimental)")
val lagomServiceLocatorEnabled = settingKey[Boolean]("Enable/Disable the service locator")
val lagomServiceLocatorStart = taskKey[Unit]("Start the service locator")
val lagomServiceLocatorStop = taskKey[Unit]("Stop the service locator")

// cassandra tasks and settings
val lagomCassandraStart = taskKey[Unit]("Start the local cassandra server")
val lagomCassandraStop = taskKey[Unit]("Stop the local cassandra server")
val lagomCassandraPort = settingKey[Int]("Port used by the local cassandra server")
val lagomCassandraEnabled = settingKey[Boolean]("Enable/Disable the cassandra server")
val lagomCassandraCleanOnStart = settingKey[Boolean]("Wipe the cassandra database before starting")
@deprecated("Configure in application.conf instead.", "1.3.2")
val lagomCassandraKeyspace = settingKey[String]("Cassandra keyspace used by a Lagom service")
val lagomCassandraJvmOptions = settingKey[Seq[String]]("JVM options used by the forked cassandra process")
val lagomCassandraMaxBootWaitingTime = settingKey[FiniteDuration]("Max waiting time to start cassandra")

// kafka tasks and settings
val lagomKafkaStart = taskKey[Unit]("Start the local kafka server")
val lagomKafkaStop = taskKey[Unit]("Stop the local kafka server")
val lagomKafkaPropertiesFile = settingKey[Option[File]]("Properties file used by the local kafka broker")
val lagomKafkaEnabled = settingKey[Boolean]("Enable/Disable the kafka server")
val lagomKafkaCleanOnStart = settingKey[Boolean]("Wipe the kafka log before starting")
val lagomKafkaJvmOptions = settingKey[Seq[String]]("JVM options used by the forked kafka process")
@deprecated("Use lagomKafkaZookeeperPort instead", "1.3.6")
val lagomKafkaZookeperPort = settingKey[Int]("Port used by the local zookeeper server (kafka requires zookeeper)")
val lagomKafkaZookeeperPort = settingKey[Int]("Port used by the local zookeeper server (kafka requires zookeeper)")
val lagomKafkaPort = settingKey[Int]("Port used by the local kafka broker")
val lagomKafkaAddress = settingKey[String]("Address of the kafka brokers (comma-separated list)")
```